# Why does "agree" have only one "g"?

Tags: orthography, latin, prefixes, french, doubled-consonants

According to Webster, *agree* comes from Latin *ad* + *gratus.* However there are other words such as *aggregate* and *aggression* that also come from *ad* + [something], and these words are spelled with a double "g" while *agree* only has a single "g". Why does *agree* have only one "g"?

Comment: If you want to try and understand the vagaries of English spelling, take a look at David Crystal's excellent book *Spell It Out*. Why is committee spelled with three double letters when the French word it derives from *comité* has none. Maybe a committee decided it should be that way!

Comment: Because English spelling is very irregular?

Answer (score 14):

Per the [online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=agree&allowed_in_frame=0) the word comes to English via Old French *agreer* which was derived from *a gré* literally *to one's liking*.

This did come from *ad gratum* but not without a lengthy trip through France.

The double-g wasn't present in the phrase *a gré* hence not brought over.

Comment: You were first by 6 seconds! I'll kill mine - feel free to steal anything in it you like.

Comment: @StoneyB no worries. I wouldn't object to you keeping yours.

Comment: I am still a tad bit confused. Did the French prefer not to `aggregate` or become `aggressive`? These words traveled to England by a different route?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is all a bit more complicated. In Middle English we find agry, agree, but also aggre, aggree etc. In Middle French too we have agrer, agreer, but also aggreer etc. So the decision to spell it with just one g in Modern English and Modern French is rather arbitrary. Mediaeval Latin aggreare is a back-formation from French.

Comment: I'll upvote, if you can provide any documented reference/evidence :)

Comment: Up- and down-voting is of no importance to me, but documentation is: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4146?rskey=8LGWzm&result=2#eid; http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agreer

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a subscription to the OED and in the second French link there were no words beginning with *agg*.

Comment: The spellings in ME and MF are listed in the OED. You should be able to find it in any well-stocked library.

Comment: For MF there is also this: http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXdXrmXaihe;XLEMME=agr%E9er;ETYM=gratus;MENU=menu_dmf;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s161d2d38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;AFFICHAGE=5

Comment: I doubt I'll find a copy of the OED in the local Italian library  where I live. :( But I did find: *Pour avoir fait et aggreer le chemin.* in agreer.2, so thank you! You should add the third link in your answer, it's relevant.