# Is "aggr-" a prefix and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, prefixes

I'm not sure if "aggr-" is a prefix but I can see some words starting with it. like:

- Aggregate
- Aggressive
- Aggravate
- Aggrieve
- Aggrandize

I'm here to ask if it has some meanings or they are all started with "aggre-" by chance.

Comment: Word 1: **aggregate** - *from Latin **aggregat-** ‘herded together’, from the verb **aggregare**, from **ad-** ‘towards’ + **grex, greg-** ‘a flock’.* Word 2: **aggressive** - *from Latin **aggress-** ‘attacked’ (from the verb **aggredi**) + -**ive***. You can do the rest for yourself by googling **[word] etymology**, but obviously the *first* two are different.

Comment: *Aggr-* is not a prefix. You can easily verify that by trying to append it to any word at all. It will not work. Ever. While the whole job of a prefix is to be easily appendable to any number of words as long as they fit the bill of that particular prefix. No word at all can fit the bill of *aggr* because it has no bill.

Comment: (1) So perhaps the answer (from FumbleFingers) is:  *aggr-* is not a prefix.  If we have a prefix here it is the Latin prefix *ad-* which changes to *ag-* when it precedes a *g*.  (2) Alternate answer: nowadays, *agri-* is a short form of *agriculture* so we do, indeed, say things like *agribusiness*.  Yes, here it seems to act as a prefix.  So *aggr-* is not a prefix, but *agri-* is.

Comment: What is "unclear" here? Everyone may not be as much a pandit as the close voters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *aggr-* is not a prefix. Latin had a prepositional prefix *ad-* that turned into *ag-* before *g-.* In the course of French's development from Latin, the preposition *ad* and the prefix *ad-* lost their final consonant sound. But French words formed with that prefix were sometimes spelled with doubled consonants in imitation of Latin practice (but not always: see fdb's answer to *[Why does “agree” have only one “g”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/163306/77227)*).

The *aggr-* sequence in all of the words that you list was originally formed by adding the Latin prefix *ad- (ag-)* or the French prefix *a- (ag-)* to bases starting with *gr-.* *Aggrieve* has the same etymological base as *aggravate* (the *ie* in *aggrieve* is from a French sound change).

The bases of the other words (*grand-, greg-, gress-*) go back to separate Latin roots. Although their pre-Latin etymologies seem a bit uncertain, I don't know of any proposals for etymologies that connect any of these roots.

Comment: Some users are casting their votes to close this question.